# network and asynchronous methods in ios7

Tags: ios, networking, asynchronous, connectivity

I was wondering how to manage a way to loading datas asynchronously when the network is back. I mean, can I know if the network is back on the device ? Or do I have to perform a recursive call on my asynchronous method each times that the datas aren't retrieved ? I tried to do a loop that way, but the cpu is exploding and of course it's not possible to let it that way.
Anyone has an idea on that subject ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I check for internet connectivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660284/when-should-i-check-for-internet-connectivity)

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660284/when-should-i-check-for-internet-connectivity and for general internet connectivity this article - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812459/easiest-way-to-detect-a-connection-on-ios

Comment: You can use Reachability class to know the network status.